# How to make like this in bootstrap with CSS?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to make like this in *bootstrap* with *CSS*? 
[image]

Comment: I'll create a quick sample for you now

Comment: check my new answer

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will suffice;

**HTML**:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="c">
        <div id="d">
            <ul>
                <li>Ford</li>
                <li>Ford</li>
                <li>Ford</li>
                <li>Ford</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div id="e">
             <ul>
                <li>Ford</li>
                <li>Ford</li>
                <li>Ford</li>
                <li>Ford</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#a{
    width: 849px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 3px solid #199ae2;
}
#b{
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #199ae2;
    display: inline-block
}
#b::after{
    content: "";
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 90px solid #199ae2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 251px;
}
#c{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 510px;
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 350px;
}
#d{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
#d > ul{
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #199ae2;
}
#d > ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 0px 30px 0px;
    border-right: 2px solid;
}
#e > ul{
    margin-top: 3px;
}
#e > ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 0px 30px 0px;
    border-right: 2px solid;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w78u7465/1/

Please know that, `StackOverflow` isn't a programming service. We are here to help you with any **problems** that you encounter while programming & not to actually develop your website. The only reason I am doing this is because it's Christmas and I'm feeling generous :-)

In future, consider learning **HTML** & **CSS** yourself, to program your own website.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.right-arrow {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 background: orange;
 padding:0 15px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  height:50px;
}
.right-arrow:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;  
 position: absolute;
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-right: 25px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
 border-left: 25px solid orange;
}
.content{
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-shrink:0;
  background-color:green;
  height:50px;
  padding-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="right-arrow">Div with Right Arrow</div>
<div class="content">
  Here you can put the links
  </div>
    </div>
```